# How to pass variables in spark SQL, using python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing spark code in python.
How do I pass a variable in a spark.sql query?

```
    q25 = 500
    Q1 = spark.sql("SELECT col1 from table where col2>500 limit $q25 , 1")
```

Currently the above code does not work? How do we pass variables?

I have also tried,

```
    Q1 = spark.sql("SELECT col1 from table where col2>500 limit q25='{}' , 1".format(q25))
```

Comment: have you tried ? 
  Q1 = spark.sql("SELECT col1 from table where col2>500 limit q25='%s' , 1"%(q25)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python has a similar variable interpolation like "string #{var}" in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788472/does-python-has-a-similar-variable-interpolation-like-string-var-in-ruby)

Comment: It's just a string... You're question isn't really about Spark

Answer (score 23):

You need to remove single quote and `q25` in string formatting like this:

```
Q1 = spark.sql("SELECT col1 from table where col2>500 limit {}, 1".format(q25))
```

**Update:**

Based on your new queries:

```
spark.sql("SELECT col1 from table where col2>500 order by col1 desc limit {}, 1".format(q25))
```

Note that the SparkSQL does not support OFFSET, so the query cannot work.

If you need add multiple variables you can try this way:

```
q25 = 500
var2 = 50
Q1 = spark.sql("SELECT col1 from table where col2>{0} limit {1}".format(var2,q25))
```

Comment: This is still giving me mismatched input exception :  spark.sql(SELECT col1 from table where col2>500 order by col1 desc limit {}, 1".format(q25))

Comment: mismatched input for ','

Comment: before SELECT, you need double quotes.

Comment: I have used " Looks llike the query does not work with ,1 i.e OFFSET is not supported in spark sql. any work arounds?

Comment: @Viv yes, you are right, SparkSQL does not support OFFSET. you can refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560815/in-pyspark-hivecontext-what-is-the-equivalent-of-sql-offset

Comment: Now how to add the second {} if there are 2 variables i want to use?

Answer (score 9):

Using f-Strings approach (PySpark):

```
table = 'my_schema.my_table'

df = spark.sql(f'select * from {table}')
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option if you're doing this sort of thing often or want to make your code easier to re-use is to use a map of configuration variables and the format option:

```
configs = {"q25":10,
           "TABLE_NAME":"my_table",
           "SCHEMA":"my_schema"}
Q1 = spark.sql("""SELECT col1 from {SCHEMA}.{TABLE_NAME} 
                  where col2>500 
                  limit {q25}
               """.format(**configs))
```

Comment: this looks great. however, it doesn't work as it says name: 'configs' is not defined. What am I missing? @David Maddox

Comment: found the mistake , if you're using jupyter notebook you have to write the dictionary in the same cell as well

Answer (score 2):

A really easy solution is to store the query as a string (using the usual python formatting), and then pass it to the `spark.sql()` function:

```
q25 = 500

query = "SELECT col1 from table where col2>500 limit {}".format(q25)

Q1 = spark.sql(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add s (String interpolator) to the string. This allows the usage of variable directly into the string.

```
val q25 = 10
Q1 = spark.sql(s"SELECT col1 from table where col2>500 limit $q25)
```

Comment: The solution you have provided is for Python or some other language? It seems off-beat...

Comment: This appears to be the scala implementation.