# Pass a python variable into an SQL query

Tags: python, sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I am working on Databricks and I am trying to pass a python variable into a SQL query:

```
series_name "LogTest"

query = """SELECT * FROM results_table
  WHERE name = $series_name
  """
spark.sql(query).toPandas()
```

I tried with `$` but it does not work.

How do I do this?

Regards

Comment: Why not use `f-string` to format the query?

Comment: look this example   :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582450/how-to-pass-variables-in-spark-sql-using-python

Comment: is this a python code? any reason '=' is missing the first line?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, your variable and queries are just strings. You can do:

```
query = f"""SELECT * FROM results_table
WHERE name = '{series_name}'
"""
```

... in python 3. Remember that your query string needs the single quotes around the inserted variable. However, for certain variables, you may need to pass the variable directly to the spark module so it can interpret it. I use pyodbc a lot and would do this:

```
query = f"""SELECT * FROM results_table
WHERE name = ?"""
cursor.execute(query, series_name)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried with f-string but I did not put the single quotes ('). Normally it works without it

Answer (score 1):

Following will also work,

```
series_name = "LogTest"
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM results_table WHERE name = " + series_name).toPandas()
```

Answer (score 0):

we can also try the following.

```
series_name = "LogTest"
query = "SELECT * FROM results_table WHERE name = {}".format(series_name)
spark.sql(query).toPandas() #
```