# Not able Convert String to Date in Spark.Sql, getting error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am not able to convert string to date format in spark.sql. When I am passing the raw string , it is converted successfully but when I am trying to store that value in a variable and passing that argument , getting type mismatch error. Tried many different techniques but still getting the same error. Can someone please help me with this thing :

```
>>> s
'2020-10-23'
>>> type(s)
<type 'str'>
>>> spark.sql("""select cast('2020-10-23' as date)""").show()
+------------------------+                                                      
|CAST(2020-10-23 AS DATE)|
+------------------------+
|              2020-10-23|
+------------------------+

>>> spark.sql("""select cast("""+s+""" as date)""").show()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.1-1.cdh6.2.1.p4355.6905851/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 778, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.1-1.cdh6.2.1.p4355.6905851/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.1-1.cdh6.2.1.p4355.6905851/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'CAST(((2020 - 10) - 23) AS DATE)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast int to date; line 1 pos 7;\n'Project [unresolvedalias(cast(((2020 - 10) - 23) as date), None)]\n+- OneRowRelation\n"


>>> spark.sql("""select cast("""+str(s)+""" as date)""").show()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.1-1.cdh6.2.1.p4355.6905851/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 778, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.1-1.cdh6.2.1.p4355.6905851/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.1-1.cdh6.2.1.p4355.6905851/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'CAST(((2020 - 10) - 23) AS DATE)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast int to date; line 1 pos 7;\n'Project [unresolvedalias(cast(((2020 - 10) - 23) as date), None)]\n+- OneRowRelation\n"
>>> 
>>> s
'2020-10-23'
>>> type(s)
<type 'str'>
>>> 
>>> spark.sql("""select cast(date_format("""+s+""",'yyyy-MM-dd') as date)""").show()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.1-1.cdh6.2.1.p4355.6905851/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 778, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.1-1.cdh6.2.1.p4355.6905851/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.1-1.cdh6.2.1.p4355.6905851/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'date_format(((2020 - 10) - 23), 'yyyy-MM-dd')' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires timestamp type, however, '((2020 - 10) - 23)' is of int type.; line 1 pos 12;\n'Project [unresolvedalias(cast(date_format(((2020 - 10) - 23), yyyy-MM-dd, Some(America/New_York)) as date), None)]\n+- OneRowRelation\n"
>>>
```

Comment: @Charlieface , I have tried with that also, but still no luck . Can you please give me the exact spark.sql, i will run and see

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass variables in spark SQL, using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582450/how-to-pass-variables-in-spark-sql-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing single quotes that surround `s`:

```
spark.sql("""select cast('"""+s+"""' as date)""")
```

---

To convince yourself that the single quotes are needed, you can print your query

```
print("""select cast("""+s+""" as date)""")
```

And you will see

```
select cast(2020-10-23 as date)
```

where the single quotes are missing.

---

Alternatively, you can define `s` as a string containing single quotes:

```
s = "'2020-10-23'"
```