# Pass variables in pyspark SQL statement

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to insert multiple variables in a Spark SQL statement and found a similar question here:
[How to pass variables in spark SQL, using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582450/how-to-pass-variables-in-spark-sql-using-python)
My question is how to do this with a list of multiple variables that are string variables (Department variable below)? It's working for Floats/ integers. I've tried several variations of syntax, but I get a "Mismatched input 'From' expecting EOF " error.

```
configs = {"lim":10,
           "codes":"A",
           "department": " 'A', 'B', 'C'", ## this is what's not working
           "salary": "100.00, 200.00"
}

df = spark.sql("""SELECT col1, col2 from table
                  WHERE employee_id IN ({department})
AND salary IN ({salary})
                 LIMIT 10
               """.format(**configs))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the single quotes:

`"department": " \'A\', \'B\', \'C\'"`

Comment: Have you also tried double backslash, e.g. \\'A\\' or doubling up your single quotes e.g. ' ' A ' '